# Read AR System Database and export to TXT file via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, connection

I have a BMC Remedy database with the AR System driver. I need to read this database, extract the information and save it in TXT.
I've searched in several places and found nothing. I tried to build something with what I was reading, but it is not working very well.

```
dim sql 
dim connectionString
Dim bindingSource1
Dim myAdapter
Dim commandBuilder

connectionString="DRIVER={AR System ODBC     Driver};ARServer=10.2.67.22;ARServerPort=1530;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx;ARAuthentication=;SERVER=NotTheServer"

sql="SELECT ""Controle_Crachá"".""Request ID FROM Controle_Crachá Controle_Crachá"

Me.SQLDS_reportresults.DataSource = bindingSource1


myAdapter= New OdbcDataAdapter(sql, connectionString)
commandBuilder= New OdbcCommandBuilder(myAdapter)

Dim table As New DataTable()

table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

myAdapter.Fill(table)

bindingSource1.DataSource = table

Me.SQLDS_reportresults.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)
```

Comment: Which error-message is shown ? Share with us the full error message. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, the message it presents is from line to line, it is a generic message.